# How to set style triggers to a Path binding parent state on UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app using c# and XAML; In the project I have a Resouce dictionary where several Path icons are, I want this icons to change the color when the parent control has the Pointer Over, I did make this on WPF app with Style data triggers:

```
<Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

But in UWP I know this works diferent but I can't figure it out I firstly tried creating a Path Style:

```
 <Style TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <Setter.Value>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2B71E"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I know this is not correct because it need's to bind the parent state not this actual state, but not just that, this give me the error:

> The property "VisualStateGroups" does not have an accessible setter.

So I opted for setting it up inside the path this way:

```
 <Path x:Key="printIcon" Width="44" Height="43" Canvas.Left="16" Canvas.Top="17" Stretch="Fill" Data="F1 M 25,27L 25,17L 51,17L 51,27L 47,27L 47,21L 29,21L 29,27L 25,27 Z M 16,28L 60,28L 60,51L 51,51L 51,60L 25,60L 25,51L 16,51L 16,28 Z M 55,46L 55,33L 21,33L 21,46L 55,46 Z M 25,44L 25,39L 51,39L 51,44L 25,44 Z ">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2B71E"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Path>
```

But now I'm dealing with

> The name "PointerOver" is already defined in this scope.
>   And this don't fix the binding with the parent state

So I think I'm lost, how can I achieve changing the fill color or the path by the state of the parent?

Comment: Is the parent always going to be a button?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this...

"path" is stored as a string resource for reuse, then use the visual states of the UI control that already exist.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="Icon_Printer">F1 M 25,27L 25,17L 51,17L 51,27L 47,27L 47,21L 29,21L 29,27L 25,27 Z M 16,28L 60,28L 60,51L 51,51L 51,60L 25,60L 25,51L 16,51L 16,28 Z M 55,46L 55,33L 21,33L 21,46L 55,46 Z M 25,44L 25,39L 51,39L 51,44L 25,44 Z</x:String>
    <Color x:Key="Color_Base">#FFF2B71E</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Color_Hover">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush_Base" Color="{StaticResource Color_Base}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush_Hover" Color="{StaticResource Color_Hover}" />
    <Style x:Key="PrinterButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource Brush_Hover}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Icon">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumColor}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Path x:Name="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="{StaticResource Icon_Printer}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Foreground="{StaticResource Brush_Base}" Style="{StaticResource PrinterButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```